# retrofit response body null

Tags: android, post, request, retrofit2

when I post request response body getting null but status 200 ?

what I'm doing wrong ?

**here is my call method**

```
  private void getTransferBtwCenterAndOffice(){

    showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.wait_message));
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    String userName = tinyDb.getString(Constant.userName);
    String passWord = tinyDb.getString(Constant.token);
    List<TransferCenterStoreParameters> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    parameters.add(new TransferCenterStoreParameters("StoreCode","B201"));
    String base = userName + ":" + passWord;
    String authHeader = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
    Call<TransferCenterStoreResponse> call = apiService.TRANSFER_CENTER_STORE_RESPONSE_CALL(authHeader,"BR_SP_BRN_GET_STORE_ACTIVE_SHIPMENTS",parameters);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<TransferCenterStoreResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TransferCenterStoreResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<TransferCenterStoreResponse> response) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onResponseeeeeeeee: "+response);
            if(response != null && response.body() != null){
                if(response.body().getTransferBtwCenterStoreResult().getResultCode().equals("200")){
                    List<TransferCenterStore> mList = response.body().getTransferCenterStoresList();
                }
                else{
                    getAlert(response.body().getTransferBtwCenterStoreResult().getErrorMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TransferCenterStoreResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            Log.e(CLASS_NAME, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

**here is my apiinterface**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("GetDispatchList")
    Call<TransferCenterStoreResponse> TRANSFER_CENTER_STORE_RESPONSE_CALL(
            @Header("Authorization") String authHeader,
            @Field("ProcName") String procName,
            @Field("Parameters") List<TransferCenterStoreParameters> objects) ;
```

**here is my parameter body**

> {
>                   "ProcName" :"BR_SP_BRN_GET_STORE_ACTIVE_SHIPMENTS",
>                   "Parameters": [
>       {
>         "Name": "StoreCode",
>         "Value": "B201"
>       }   ] }

**here is my transfercenterstoreresponse class**

```
public class TransferCenterStoreResponse {

    @SerializedName("ResultModel")
    private TransferBtwCenterStoreResult transferBtwCenterStoreResult;

    @SerializedName("Dispatches")
    private List<TransferCenterStore> transferCenterStoresList;


    public TransferBtwCenterStoreResult getTransferBtwCenterStoreResult() {
        return transferBtwCenterStoreResult;
    }

    public void setTransferBtwCenterStoreResult(TransferBtwCenterStoreResult transferBtwCenterStoreResult) {
        this.transferBtwCenterStoreResult = transferBtwCenterStoreResult;
    }

    public List<TransferCenterStore> getTransferCenterStoresList() {
        return transferCenterStoresList;
    }

    public void setTransferCenterStoresList(List<TransferCenterStore> transferCenterStoresList) {
        this.transferCenterStoresList = transferCenterStoresList;
    }
}
```

**here is my response**

```
{
    "ResultModel": {
        "ResultStatus": "Success",
        "ResultCode": "200",
        "ErrorMessage": null,
        "Token": "BD0F1E3D1F8E43B79BCE96FA6572A2AD",
        "ResultJson": "",
        "ConnectionUrl": "http://192.168.3.40:1313/",
        "UserName": null,
        "ResultNative": "",
        "ResultDt": null
    },
    "Dispatches": [
        {
            "ShippingNumber": "178-S-6-30770",
            "ShippingDate": "2018-02-11T21:00:00Z",
            "Description": "",
            "InternalDescription": "",
            "SeriesNumber": 322216,
            "LogisticsCompanyBOL": "",
            "WarehouseCode": "B456",
            "ShipmentHeaderID": "3408fcec-9e8f-4e82-b556-a88500d3713f",
            "Quantitity": 1
        }
]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your TransferCenterStoreResponse class?

Comment: post your response json code getting on server.

Comment: I posted @AndroidTeam

Comment: @GeethakrishnaJuluri any advice ?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

if you getting 200 and getting json data from the server then make sure your response pojo class all the key same as json key given by server.

check your pojo class like below..

```
public class DispatchesItem{
private String description;
private int quantitity;
private String shippingNumber;
private String shippingDate;
private int seriesNumber;
private String shipmentHeaderID;
private String internalDescription;
private String warehouseCode;
private String logisticsCompanyBOL;

public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public void setQuantitity(int quantitity){
    this.quantitity = quantitity;
}

public int getQuantitity(){
    return quantitity;
}

public void setShippingNumber(String shippingNumber){
    this.shippingNumber = shippingNumber;
}

public String getShippingNumber(){
    return shippingNumber;
}

public void setShippingDate(String shippingDate){
    this.shippingDate = shippingDate;
}

public String getShippingDate(){
    return shippingDate;
}

public void setSeriesNumber(int seriesNumber){
    this.seriesNumber = seriesNumber;
}

public int getSeriesNumber(){
    return seriesNumber;
}

public void setShipmentHeaderID(String shipmentHeaderID){
    this.shipmentHeaderID = shipmentHeaderID;
}

public String getShipmentHeaderID(){
    return shipmentHeaderID;
}

public void setInternalDescription(String internalDescription){
    this.internalDescription = internalDescription;
}

public String getInternalDescription(){
    return internalDescription;
}

public void setWarehouseCode(String warehouseCode){
    this.warehouseCode = warehouseCode;
}

public String getWarehouseCode(){
    return warehouseCode;
}

public void setLogisticsCompanyBOL(String logisticsCompanyBOL){
    this.logisticsCompanyBOL = logisticsCompanyBOL;
}

public String getLogisticsCompanyBOL(){
    return logisticsCompanyBOL;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "DispatchesItem{" + 
        "description = '" + description + '\'' + 
        ",quantitity = '" + quantitity + '\'' + 
        ",shippingNumber = '" + shippingNumber + '\'' + 
        ",shippingDate = '" + shippingDate + '\'' + 
        ",seriesNumber = '" + seriesNumber + '\'' + 
        ",shipmentHeaderID = '" + shipmentHeaderID + '\'' + 
        ",internalDescription = '" + internalDescription + '\'' + 
        ",warehouseCode = '" + warehouseCode + '\'' + 
        ",logisticsCompanyBOL = '" + logisticsCompanyBOL + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
}


public class ResultModel{
private String resultJson;
private Object userName;
private String resultStatus;
private String connectionUrl;
private String token;
private String resultNative;
private Object resultDt;
private Object errorMessage;
private String resultCode;

public void setResultJson(String resultJson){
    this.resultJson = resultJson;
}

public String getResultJson(){
    return resultJson;
}

public void setUserName(Object userName){
    this.userName = userName;
}

public Object getUserName(){
    return userName;
}

public void setResultStatus(String resultStatus){
    this.resultStatus = resultStatus;
}

public String getResultStatus(){
    return resultStatus;
}

public void setConnectionUrl(String connectionUrl){
    this.connectionUrl = connectionUrl;
}

public String getConnectionUrl(){
    return connectionUrl;
}

public void setToken(String token){
    this.token = token;
}

public String getToken(){
    return token;
}

public void setResultNative(String resultNative){
    this.resultNative = resultNative;
}

public String getResultNative(){
    return resultNative;
}

public void setResultDt(Object resultDt){
    this.resultDt = resultDt;
}

public Object getResultDt(){
    return resultDt;
}

public void setErrorMessage(Object errorMessage){
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

public Object getErrorMessage(){
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setResultCode(String resultCode){
    this.resultCode = resultCode;
}

public String getResultCode(){
    return resultCode;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "ResultModel{" + 
        "resultJson = '" + resultJson + '\'' + 
        ",userName = '" + userName + '\'' + 
        ",resultStatus = '" + resultStatus + '\'' + 
        ",connectionUrl = '" + connectionUrl + '\'' + 
        ",token = '" + token + '\'' + 
        ",resultNative = '" + resultNative + '\'' + 
        ",resultDt = '" + resultDt + '\'' + 
        ",errorMessage = '" + errorMessage + '\'' + 
        ",resultCode = '" + resultCode + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
  }
```

and your response class

```
public class Response{
@SerializedName("Dispatches")
private List<DispatchesItem> dispatches;
@SerializedName("ResultModel")
private ResultModel resultModel;

public void setDispatches(List<DispatchesItem> dispatches){
    this.dispatches = dispatches;
}

public List<DispatchesItem> getDispatches(){
    return dispatches;
}

public void setResultModel(ResultModel resultModel){
    this.resultModel = resultModel;
}

public ResultModel getResultModel(){
    return resultModel;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "Response{" + 
        "dispatches = '" + dispatches + '\'' + 
        ",resultModel = '" + resultModel + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
```

}

put all pojo class field above  @SerializedName("json key") in to your json key.